# Values always visible in console.log but sometimes not visible in input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I ran into a problem which I am not sure how to fix.
When I drag the knob into the picture a clone is created.
Below the image, a form is then shown with the position of the button.
The problem is that sometimes this value is not updated in this input field.

In line 85 I set that value.
Then on lines 89 and 90 I check if this value is there in the first place.
By means of:
console.log(ui.position.left);
console.log($("#dragItemPositionX[data-id=" + UUID + "]").val());

A value always appears here but when I look at the form I sometimes see no value in the input field.
( As a test case for this, drag a button to the picture a few times. Sometimes you will see no value in the input field.

How is this possible and how can I fix this?

```
function uuid() {
  var dt = new Date().getTime();
  var uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
    var r = (dt + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
    dt = Math.floor(dt / 16);
    return (c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8)).toString(16);
  });
  return uuid;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Create default knob
  $('#knob').jqxKnob({
    width: 34,
    height: 34,
    disabled: true,
    value: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    startAngle: 120,
    endAngle: 420,
    snapToStep: true,
    rotation: 'clockwise',
    style: {
      stroke: '#000',
      strokeWidth: 1,
      fill: {
        color: '#fff'
      }
    },
    pointer: {
      type: 'line',
      thickness: 4,
      style: {
        fill: "#00a4e1",
        stroke: "#00a4e1"
      },
      size: '70%',
      offset: '0%'
    }
  });

  //Drag default knob in #droppable div

  $(".draggable").draggable({
    containment: "#droppable",
    appendTo: "#droppable",
    helper: "clone"
  });
});

  // Drag&Drop default knob

  $("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {

      //Generate UUID
      var UUID = uuid();

      // Change class in order to stop the cloning in droppable div.

      if (ui.draggable.hasClass("draggable")) {
        var $item = $(ui.helper).clone();
        $item.removeClass("draggable");
        $item.addClass("editable");
        $item.attr('data-id', UUID);
        $(this).append($item);
  $(".editable").draggable({
    containment: "#droppable",
    appendTo: "#droppable",
    drag: function(event, ui) {
     $("#dragItemPositionX[data-id=" + UUID + "]").val(ui.position.left);
        $("#dragItemPositionY[data-id=" + UUID + "]").val(ui.position.top);
    }
  });
        //Add a form  & fill some values

        $("#info").append("<form class='pure-form knob' name=" + UUID + " data-id=" + UUID + ">");
        $("form[data-id=" + UUID + "]").append($("#template").html());
        $("form[data-id=" + UUID + "]").find('input').each(function() {
          $('input').attr('data-id', UUID);
          $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name') + "[]");
        });

        $("#dragItemPositionX[data-id=" + UUID + "]").val(ui.position.left);
        $("#dragItemPositionY[data-id=" + UUID + "]").val(ui.position.top);


        console.log(ui.position.left);
        console.log($("#dragItemPositionX[data-id=" + UUID + "]").val());

        // Show form and active knob

        $("form.knob").hide();
        $("form[data-id=" + UUID + "]").show();
        $("body").find(".active_knob").removeClass("active_knob");
        $(".jqx-knob[data-id=" + UUID + "]").find("line").eq(-1).addClass("active_knob");
      }
    }
  })
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2c69kfy0/)

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: There is a jsfiddle in the openingspost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made some minor updates. You had a few items outside of your jQuery block. I suspect that you had some syntax issues.

Test: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/acr1dvbf/5/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  function uuid() {
    var dt = new Date().getTime();
    var uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
      var r = (dt + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
      dt = Math.floor(dt / 16);
      return (c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8)).toString(16);
    });
    return uuid;
  }

  // Create default knob
  $('#knob').jqxKnob({
    width: 34,
    height: 34,
    disabled: true,
    value: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    startAngle: 120,
    endAngle: 420,
    snapToStep: true,
    rotation: 'clockwise',
    style: {
      stroke: '#000',
      strokeWidth: 1,
      fill: {
        color: '#fff'
      }
    },
    pointer: {
      type: 'line',
      thickness: 4,
      style: {
        fill: "#00a4e1",
        stroke: "#00a4e1"
      },
      size: '70%',
      offset: '0%'
    }
  });

  //Drag default knob in #droppable div

  $(".draggable").draggable({
    containment: "#droppable",
    appendTo: "#droppable",
    helper: "clone"
  });

  // Drag&Drop default knob

  $("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {

      //Generate UUID
      var UUID = uuid();

      // Change class in order to stop the cloning in droppable div.

      if (ui.draggable.hasClass("draggable")) {
        var $item = $(ui.helper).clone();
        $item.toggleClass("draggable editable");
        $item.attr('data-id', UUID);
        $(this).append($item);
        $(".editable").draggable({
          containment: "#droppable",
          appendTo: "#droppable",
          drag: function(event, ui) {
            $("#dragItemPositionX[data-id=" + UUID + "]").val(ui.position.left);
            $("#dragItemPositionY[data-id=" + UUID + "]").val(ui.position.top);
          }
        });
        //Add a form  & fill some values

        $("#info").append("<form class='pure-form knob' name=" + UUID + " data-id=" + UUID + ">");
        $("form[data-id=" + UUID + "]").append($("#template").html());
        $("form[data-id=" + UUID + "]").find('input').each(function(i, el) {
          $('input').attr('data-id', UUID);
          $(el).attr('name', $(this).attr('name') + "[]");
        });

        $("#dragItemPositionX[data-id=" + UUID + "]").val(ui.position.left);
        $("#dragItemPositionY[data-id=" + UUID + "]").val(ui.position.top);


        console.log(ui.position.left);
        console.log($("#dragItemPositionX[data-id=" + UUID + "]").val());

        // Show form and active knob

        $("form.knob").hide();
        $("form[data-id=" + UUID + "]").show();
        $(".active_knob").removeClass("active_knob");
        $(".jqx-knob[data-id=" + UUID + "]").find("line").eq(-1).addClass("active_knob");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

When I move the clone around, I always get value updates.

**Update**

If you add more knobs, you will then need to conditionally Add the knob or if it's an existing knob, show the correct form and show the proper position.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/acr1dvbf/95/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  function getId() {
    var dt = new Date().getTime();
    var uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
      var r = (dt + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
      dt = Math.floor(dt / 16);
      return (c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8)).toString(16);
    });
    return uuid;
  }

  function makeKnobDrag(item) {
    return $(item).draggable({
      containment: "#droppable",
      drag: function(event, ui) {
        $("#knob-form-" + $(item).data("form") + " .drag-x").val(ui.position.left);
        $("#knob-form-" + $(item).data("form") + " .drag-y").val(ui.position.top);
      }
    });
  }

  function getActiveKnobPosition() {
    return $(".active_knob").closest(".jqx-knob").position();
  }

  function makeForm(target, uuid) {
    var c = $(".active_knob").closest(".jqx-knob").data("form");
    var form = $("<form>", {
      class: "pure-form knob",
      name: uuid,
      "data-id": uuid,
      id: "knob-form-" + c
    }).appendTo(target);
    form.append($("#template form").children().clone());
    form.find('input').each(function(i, el) {
      $(el).attr({
        name: $(el).attr("name") + "[]",
        "data-id": uuid,
        id: $(el).attr("id").substring(0, $(el).attr("id").indexOf("-")) + c
      });
    });
    $("form.knob").hide();
    var kPos = getActiveKnobPosition();
    $(".drag-x", form).val(kPos.left);
    $(".drag-y", form).val(kPos.top);
    form.show();
  }


  // Create default knob
  $('#knob').jqxKnob({
    width: 34,
    height: 34,
    disabled: true,
    value: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    startAngle: 120,
    endAngle: 420,
    snapToStep: true,
    rotation: 'clockwise',
    style: {
      stroke: '#000',
      strokeWidth: 1,
      fill: {
        color: '#fff'
      }
    },
    pointer: {
      type: 'line',
      thickness: 4,
      style: {
        fill: "#00a4e1",
        stroke: "#00a4e1"
      },
      size: '70%',
      offset: '0%'
    }
  });

  //Drag default knob in #droppable div

  $(".draggable").draggable({
    containment: "#droppable",
    helper: "clone",
    start: function(e, ui) {
      ui.helper.addClass("new-item");
    }
  });

  // Drag&Drop default knob

  $("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var $self = $(this);
      var UUID;
      var $item = $(ui.helper).clone();
      $(".active_knob").removeClass("active_knob");
      if ($item.hasClass("new-item")) {
        UUID = getId();
        $item.removeClass("new-item").toggleClass("draggable editable ui-draggable ui-draggable-dragging");
        $item.attr({
          "data-id": UUID,
          "data-form": "knob-form-" + ($("form.knob").length + 1)
        });
        $self.append($item);
        $item.find("line").eq(-1).addClass("active_knob");
        makeKnobDrag($item, UUID);
        makeForm("#info", UUID);
      } else {
        UUID = $item.data("id");
        c = $item.data("form");
        $("form.knob").hide();
        $item.find("line").eq(-1).addClass("active_knob");
        $("#knob-form-" + c).show();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

As you can see, if it's a new item, it will be added to the droppable. If it's not a new item, it will show the proper form and update the position.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the issue is still there. If you drag another knob in the image the values arent updated sometimes.

Comment: @Bits you stated, '*When I drag the knob into the picture a clone is created.*' You did not indicate a second knob needed to be created.

Comment: Ok sorry, English is not my native language. I also mentioned a testcase however in the openingspost. ( As a test case for this, drag a button to the picture a few times. Sometimes you will see no value in the input field.

Comment: I would like to have multiple knobs with different UUID's, which I can move freely in the droppable div. ( with correct positioning in the input fields for every knob)

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for the update version. I see you changed quite a bit of code. I have to look into it more to see how you made this work. Thanks again.